# Firebase data ordering

Tags: android, firebase

I feel as if I'm missing something big when I use firebase in my android app. I have been using

```
push();
```

to put my data in firebase with a unique id.
I have been accessing this data in an activity using the ChildEventListener:

```
ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {         
    // Retrieve new posts as they are added to the database
    @Override public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildKey) {
        Map<String, Object> newPost = (Map<String, Object>) snapshot.getValue();
    }
});
```

I believe that

```
snapshot.getValue()
```

should provide me with all my unique ids but how do I order them to display them in order from newest to oldest?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call:

```
ref.push().setValue(anObject);
```

Then that will fire `onChildAdded` once, with the data from `anObject` in `snapshot.getValue()`.

So in this example from the [Firebase guide for Android](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html#section-push):

```
Firebase postRef = ref.child("posts");

Map<String, String> post1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
post1.put("author", "gracehop");
post1.put("title", "Announcing COBOL, a New Programming Language");
postRef.push().setValue(post1);

Map<String, String> post2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
post2.put("author", "alanisawesome");
post2.put("title", "The Turing Machine");
postRef.push().setValue(post2);
```

Let's register our `onChildAdded` listener:

```
ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildKey) {
        System.out.println(snapshot.getKey());
    }
};
```

});

The `onChildAdded` method is called whenever a child is added to the location we register it on. We add two children, so `onChildAdded` will called twice. The first time it will fire for `gracehop` the second time for `alanisawesome`. Each time it will print the key of the corresponding node.

*Note: Firebase fires the `onChildAdded` event also for all existing children at the location. So it fires right away for all existing children, as well as whenever a child is added.*

You seem to expect that you get all values at once. If that is what you're looking for, you can accomplish it with a so-called ValueListener

```
postRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        System.out.println(snapshot.getValue());
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Note that the method is called `onDataChange` here. So this method is called whenever the data at the location changes. Since you add the children under where `postRef`, the `onDataChange` method will be called twice. The first time with just `gracehop`, the second time with both `gracehop` and `alanisawesome`.

You can loop over the nodes in a `DataSnapshot` with:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
        System.out.println(postSnapshot.getKey());
    }
}
```

If we push the two values like before, the `onDataChange` will fire twice. The first time it will print the key for `gracehop` the second time it will print the key for `gracehop` and then the key for `alanisawesome`. So it will print three values in total, where the snippet with `onChildAdded` will only print two.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I'll have to test it out a bit later. If it works I'll accept it!